# GCD of Ideal: How we get $\gcd(I, J) = I + J $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, gcd-and-lcm, maximal-and-prime-ideals, dedekind-domain

Take any two non-zero ideals $I$ and $J$ in $R$. Since we know that ideals in a Dedekind domain factors uniquely into prime ideals

$$I = \prod_i P_i^{m_i},  J = \prod_i P_i^{n_i}$$

where $P_i$’s are distinct non-zero prime ideals in $R$ and $m_i, n_i \in \mathbb{Z}$, then the greatest common divisor and least common multiple of $I$ and $J$ are respectively as following,

$\gcd(I,J)=I+J=\prod_i P_i^{\min(n_i,m_i)}, \operatorname{lcm}(I,J)=I\cap J= \prod_i P_i^{\max(n_i,m_i)}.$

How do we get $\gcd(I, J)=I+J=\prod_i P_i^{\min(n_i,m_i)}$

and

$\operatorname{lcm}(I,J)=I\cap J=\prod_i P_i^{\max(n_i,m_i)}$
?

Comment: Shouldn't the exponent on $P_i$ be $\max$ and not $\min$ for the $lcm ?$

Comment: @ChrisLeary corrected  plz  chk again.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Given a prime factorization for two integers, how would you find their $lcm$ and $gcd $? If I recall correctly (not a foregone conclusion), similar reasoning works for the ideals.-

Comment: @ChrisLeary not clear to me, cant comprehend $I+J$ as gcd.

Comment: $I+J$ is the smallest ideal that contains both $I$ and $J$ and is contained in any ideal that contains both $I$ and $J$. Similarly, $I \cap J$ is the largest ideal that is contained in both $I$ and $J$ and contains any ideal that is contained in both $I$ and $J$. These facts should suggest some properties of lcm and gcd. On a more basic level, recall that in a PID, $(b) \subseteq (a)$ if and only if $a$ divides $b$. That should get the wheels turning.

Comment: @ChrisLeary How or why $I+J$ is the smallest ideal that contains both $I$ and $J $and is contained in any ideal that contains both $I$ and $J$?

Comment: Let $K$ be an ideal that contains both $I$ and $J$. Then it must contain $i+j$ for any $i\in I,$ $j \in J.$ That is, it must contain $I+J.$

Comment: @ChrisLeary how we write that in product form $\prod_i P_i^{\min(n_i,m_i)}$ ?

Comment: That product should work. Note that $P^l \subseteq  P^k$ if $l \geq k.$ You might try running through the details when the product involves a small number of primes, even two or three. Don't be afraid to go to the special case of a PID. Consider what happens in $\mathbb{Z}$ if $I=(6}$ and $J=(14).$ Here, actual lcm and gcd will be involved. You should get an idea of how to proceed in the Dedekind domain case from this. Also, check your definitions for lcm and gcd of ideals.